# Isomorphic Dompurify.sanitize() not reading request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, http-headers, dompurify

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-dompurify in backend. When I'm passing request object in sanitize() method it is only keeping headers and removing everything else including body. Is there any way to keep the request body?

Comment: I see that isomorphic-dompurify has [a GitHub repo where they take issues](https://github.com/kkomelin/isomorphic-dompurify/issues). Perhaps that is a better avenue for support? They'll likely require a [mre], just as Stack Overflow does, though...